# Get JSON data from WEB API and print into HTML

Tags: html, json

I have a Portal (something like a landing page) for my main website.
I have something like: subdomain.mywebsite.com/portal/statistics that prints:

```
{"onlineUsers":"53","registeredUsers":"31608","connectedTodayOnWebsite":212,"connectedLastMonth":"6729"}
```

On my .html landing page have this:

```
<div class="row counters">

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
            <span data-toggle="counter-up" id="online">274</span>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
            <span data-toggle="counter-up" id="registered">421</span>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
            <span data-toggle="counter-up" id="connectedtoday">1,364</span>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
            <span data-toggle="counter-up" id="connectedlastmonth">18</span>
          </div>

        </div>
```

How can I print the numbers from API into that div/spans? I think I should use some AJAX but I really don't get it.

Comment: how do you make the API call ? From `JavaScript` or the server side.

Comment: "I think I should use some AJAX but I really don't get it."  — there are **many** tutorials out there. If you don't "get" any of them, then there is no point in us writing **another** one here. Find one. Follow it. Ask a **specific** question here with a reference to the tutorial, a *clear problem statement* and a [mcve] **if you get stuck**.

Comment: You can try this tutorial: https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-connect-to-an-api-with-javascript/  (without using ajax).

Comment: @ths I really don't know how to call. If i acces subdomain.mywebsite.com/portal/statistics from my browser I get that json.

Comment: @AndrewS. you'll need some `JavaScript` that includes an `AJAX` call to push the data into the `HTML`.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, you have to fetch the data from the API server endpoint you choose. Firsts of all you are going to have 2 differents parts, one in HTML and the other in pure Javascript. Also, you can use some JS library but in the example we're going to see a pure JS example.

The HTML is so close, for example we can do:

```
<div class="row counters">

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
    <span data-toggle="counter-up" id="online">Loading...</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
    <span data-toggle="counter-up" id="registered">Loading...</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
    <span data-toggle="counter-up" id="connectedtoday">Loading...</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
    <span data-toggle="counter-up" id="connectedlastmonth">Loading...</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

By default, the data doesn't arrived yet and we can show to the user is Loading right now. By the other side, we have a Javascript code. The firsts part of Javascript is open a connection to the server API endpoint:

```
// Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
request.open('GET', 'HERE_IS_YOUR_SERVER_API_ENDPOINT', true)

request.onload = function () {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here, MAGIC IS HERE
}

// Send request
request.send()
```

Now, we are going to work with the JSON response. Remember that is the server admin works make the server responses in JSON format and not in XML or something different.

```
// Begin accessing JSON data here
var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

// Now you can use your data, for example:
setDataValues(data)

function setDataValues (data) {
   document.getElementById('online').innerHTML = data.onlineUsers
   // Do the same with the others values
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$.getJSON(url,
function (data) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].onlineUsers+ "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].registeredUsers+ "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].connectedTodayOnWebsite+ "</td>");
 tr.append("<td>" + data[i].connectedLastMonth+ "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you please add some description to your source code?